# One output, 7 possible values. What is the proper loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My CNN's accuracy doesn't increase past about .14 when it trains. Oddly, the model works fine.  What is the proper loss function to be using for a CNN that has a single-node output, and the output value is supposed to be an integer between 1 and 7, inclusive?  (The output is a category.)

(I couldn't help but notice that .14xx * 7 is about 1.)

In addition, what should the activation function on my single-node output be?  I have specified nothing.

Comment: If this is a classification task, why don't you create a model with 7 output nodes and categorical cross-entropy as a loss function? With a single output node, all you can hope for is to solve a binary classification problem or a regression problem.

Comment: ok, hold please!

Comment: Yeo @DocDriven, that trains as expection.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear. I implemented your idea and it worked immediately - the model started training.

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a classification problem with 7 classes. Therefore the last layer in your model should be of the form

```
output=Dense(units=7, activation='softmax') (x)
```

in your model use loss as categorial_crossentropy and the coding for your labels
should be categorical